# HQL :parameter length

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

How do I perform `substring` with a parameter's length?

i.e.

```
Query query = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT * from User where substring(name, 1, :name.length()) like :name");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL query `name.length()` would not work, however you can use following

```
Query query = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().
              createQuery("SELECT * from User where substring(name, 1, :length) like :name");

query.setParameter("length",name.length());
........
........
```